OpenCV - Outer Edge Circle Detection for Cell Culture Plates
I am utilizing OpenCV and Python to located the positions of the 96-well plates in order to automate a detection process. However, I encounter an issue that the camera is built with a wide angle lens resulting in an image which is not ideal for Hough Transform to detect and locate circles, in this case wells, as the function detects the inside of the wells as a circle. I have include a sample well-image and an image of what was detected by the wells.
This is the original image.
This is the image that is detected by the Hough Transfrom in the OpenCV. The red points are the center that is detected by the Hough Transform and the black circles are circles that the OpenCV function detected.

To tackle this issue, I have tried using gray scale image before using the Hough Transform function.
import cv2 
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

img_path = "image_path" 

img = cv2.imread(img_path) # read the image
img_height, img_width, img_col_channels = img.shape # General image data
print(img_height, img_width)

gray_img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

# blurred_image = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray_img, (9, 9), 2)

# gray_img = cv2.blur(gray_img, (3,3)) # blur to reduce noise?

detected_circles = cv2.HoughCircles(gray_img, # image for detection
                                    cv2.HOUGH_GRADIENT, # detection method
                                    1, # inverse ration of resolution
                                    img_height/64, # Not sure need adjustment
                                    param1 = 200,
                                    param2 = 10,
                                    minRadius = 14, # If unknown input 0
                                    maxRadius = 15 # If unknown input 0
                                )

if detected_circles is not None:
    print("Detected") 
    detected_circles = np.uint16(np.around(detected_circles))
    for i in detected_circles[0, :96]: # define maximun number of circles is 96
        cir_center = (i[0], i[1]) # circle center tuple
        # print(cir_center)
        cir_radius = i[2] # circle radius
        cv2.circle(img, cir_center, 1, (0, 0, 255), 5) # circle center col red
        cv2.circle(img, cir_center, cir_radius, (0, 0, 0), 5) # circle outline
    cv2.imshow("Detected Circle", img) 
    cv2.waitKey(0) 
else:
    print("No circles are detected.")

cv2.destroyAllWindows()

Also, I haved tried using Canny Edge detection through this Edge detection opencv. However, through this tutorial the inner edges are still prevalent, resulting in the same result.
Any recommendations or advice would be greatly appreciated!
Updated:

Thank you fmw42 for your comment, I have updated the code for problem reproducibility and details of the image.


What are the black circles that you show and the red dots?  Are the red dots the center of the circles and the black the found circles from their diameters?  Please show more code including your imports and reading of image and writing your output so that it is a fully reproducible example.

Thank you @fmw42 for your comment. I have updated the post with the code for reproducibility. Yes, the black circles are outlines and the red dots are the HoughCircles center.

hough is a terrible approach. I'd recommend putting easy to spot markers on the 4 corners of the array (and the same height as the edges of the wells), locating those, and calculating from that (having a "model" of this array in mind). -- something "robust" would be to sharpie the corners of the thing. it's not the easiest to locate but it takes no finesse to restore if the sharpie rubs off or gets cleaned off

you can see the effect of perspective/parallax as you look into different wells. since you want this for measurements, you'd either need to put the camera further away (and use optical zoom, not digital zoom), or go rob a bank so you can pay for a "telecentric lens" the size of your microplate.

markers (my first suggestion) are not required but they make the thing a lot easier to find initially. feature matching can do that too. an initial alignment can then be refined, given a suitable model picture (I'm thinking ECC refinement because that's in OpenCV).

@ChristophRackwitz Thank you for your insights. I completely agree that my current camera setup is not ideal. I'm also experimenting with different camera positions. I appreciate your marker suggestions and will definitely explore them.

You know the exact dimensions of the case. There are vanes along the outside for which you could measure their locations. You could draw lines on the back along those vanes and find the intersections (or perhaps I see some dark spots that look like in the center of each cell. You could measure those locations). Then given all those reference positions, you could measure the same in the image). Now you have an array of reference points and their corresponding image points. You could then try to correct the image using a 2nd or 3rd order polynomial warping. Or correct assuming barrel distortion.
